# sending a variable through jquery.get function depending on which div is clicked

Tags: jquery

Heres the markup:

```
<div id='0203' class='threadWrapper'>
<div class='littleme'>
```

I am trying to send the id of a parent div as a parameter in jquery.get function:

```
$('.littleme').click(function**()**{
var id = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
$.get("PHP/viewedThread.php", {viewedURLID: id});
});
```

and am getting rather lost I'm afraid.

...ammendment...
$(this).closest(".threadWrapper").attr("id");

Comment: What *exactly* is not working? What HTTP headers are being sent? Error messages?

Comment: for a start none of the javascript which follows this gets triggered. After that I don't know as it never happens

Comment: oops apologies. syntax mistake in .click(function(){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing (not tested) that the closest is returning itself (".littleme") which without any id. If you need to target the parent div, try using [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

---

UPDATE

The Closest is acutally started from *Current* node, so, it is not going to look for parent but probably the next div follows.

quote from [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree

Comment: actually it is all working well now, it was just a little unoticed error on my part. cheers